# Create custom Prometheus metrics in NiFi

Tags: monitoring, apache-nifi, prometheus, grafana

We are going to use the Prometheus framework to monitor our NiFi instance and dataflows inside.

In order to achieve this, we already configured PrometheusReportingTask to expose pre-existing NiFi metrics.

The amount of metrics is pretty full but we would like to create custom Prometheus metrics in or custom/predefined NiFi processors and expose them using PrometheusReportingTask.

Is it possible to implement it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PrometheusReportingTask has hardcoded metrics registries and can't be extended as such. You could create your own ReportingTask that opens another port as a Prometheus scrape target and expose your metrics, then your Prometheus instance can scrape both targets.

If you don't want to code a full ReportingTask instance (and a NAR to keep it in), take a look at [ScriptedReportingTask](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.12.0/org.apache.nifi.reporting.script.ScriptedReportingTask/index.html), you can put your custom code in there so you don't need to create a project/module/NAR for your custom reporting task.